# How to run cron scheduler only once?

Tags: cron

My scheduler looks like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* 30 11 * * *")
```

That's nice. Every 11:30 it runs! works great! but if the scheduler will finish working on 11:30:10, scheduler runs again. How can I add seconds here?  Is it true?

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 30 11 * * *")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 30 11 * * *")
```